# Regex automation for replace javascript hex string into HTML entities string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

I have some strings like the following one:

```
\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E
```

and I like to convert that string in the following form:

```
&#x63;&#x68;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;
```

by using a single regex.

Currently I am using this one:

```
\\
```

and I am doing the replacement of the `\` with the value `;&#`.

Unfortunatelly, this returns the following result:

```
;&#x63;&#x68;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E
```

*Note that the result starting with the greek question mark and ends without the greek question mark*

So, is there any better way to replace the `\` with `;&#` but without the result starting with the `;` and finally the result ending with `;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the following regex:

`\\(\w+)`

and replace with:

`&#\1;`

Result: `&#x63;&#x68;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;`

### Demo

Comment: Thanks @sshashank124 :) This is what I looked for ... ! :) I just modified a bit the replace string with &#$1;

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: @MerianosNikos, Well. Really glad I could help!